# whatsapp-web.js to build ussd like menus and actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

I am using whatsapp-web.js to develop whatsapp based services so i want people to be able to register using their whatsapp and download files. I have managed to handle file management part but i am stack on implementations of QnA like functionality with the backend with predefined nested menus with their submenus or actions. I want something like below:

**To register, reply to these questions** (each questions comes after the previous one was sent as in USSD menus )

Name? :-> user types in name

Age? :-> users types in age

DOB? :-> users types in dob

Comment: If they are already registered then what is the purpose of this registration?  The WhatsApp api provides different ways to authenticate, including QR codes.

Comment: Instead of using form to register people on my website i want to be using whatsapp.Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like this: create an auto reply, ex: if someone text via whatsapp "Register" then send back something like "To register please follow [www.yourwebsite.com/register"](http://www.yourwebsite.com/register%22) once register form submitted then emit an event to send notification via whatsapp to the register that their account has been created

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I need is to have it purely on whatsapp because my users can afford whatsapp bundle (cheaper) not surfing bundle